# Safecracker Registration Form

Tags: forms, safecracker-registration

I have gone to the steps in [this](https://objectivehtml.com/safecracker-registration) page to setup safecracker registration module.

This is my form for registration.

```
{exp:safecracker
    channel="members"
    class="form-horizontal"
    dynamic_title="[email]"
    error_handling="inline"
    include_jquery="no"
    register_member="yes"
    return="index.php/sign-up/"
    safecracker_head="no"
}

    {if global_errors:count > 0}
    <div class="errors group tencol">
        <h3>General Errors</h3>

        <ul class="bullets">
        {global_errors}
            <li>{error}</li>
        {/global_errors}
        </ul>   
    </div>
    {/if}

    {if field_errors:count > 0}
    <div class="errors group tencol">
        <h3>Form Errors</h3>

        <ul class="bullets">
        {field_errors}
            <li>{error}</li>
        {/field_errors}
        </ul>   
    </div>
    {/if}

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sign Up</legend>

        {stash:embed name="forms:fields:.email"}
        {stash:embed name="forms:fields:.password"}
        {stash:embed name="forms:fields:.password-confirm"}

        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

{/exp:safecracker}
```

When I try to submit with valid fields, I get redirected to index.php/sign-up with nothing displayed at all.

Keep in mind that this form is in index.php/sign-up which means it should redirect to itself.

I don't receive any emails at all which means that registration probably failed.

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Your code looks correct. I am not immediately sure what the issue is. If the form submits back to the page, but the page appears totally white then there is likely an error on the page, or something isn't setup correctly. But from your other post, I can't tell what that is just yet. Make sure you have debugging turning on. Check to see if your member profile was created (the channel). Check to see if your member login information was created (the actual member).

Comment: Now I am getting a database error after turning debugging on. I posted the problem in a different [question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/safecracker-registration-database-error)

Comment: Just to let you know, I am working on a fix for that bug today. I should have a new version ready later today or tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to make an official answer to this post. This error was due an architectural change in EE 2.5.5. Their (EllisLab) assumption was that other developers weren't using these classes. So to cope with them breaking the API in a maintenance release, I had to fork the code to support EE 2.5.5+ and anything prior.

If you email support[at]objectivehtml.com I will send you the latest copy to test before I release to the public.

EDIT:

**I have a fix for these issue now in my latest developer build. Just email me for the latest build.**

Answer (score 1):

Try using `return="sign-up/index"`- the `index.php` is not required, as EE already knows whether you're using index.php or not.