# Safecracker Registration Database Error

Tags: safecracker-registration

I am trying to use Safecracker Registration to register but upon submit I get this error,

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'ip_address' in 'where clause'

SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM exp_security_hashes WHERE hash='56bdf8c4561f360c63ed39ad076b03f4047066f3' AND ip_address = '120.28.235.198' AND ip_address = '120.28.235.198' AND date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP()-7200

Filename: third_party/safecracker_registration/libraries/Safecracker_registration_lib.php

Line Number: 459
```

Here is my form

```
{exp:safecracker
    channel="members"
    class="form-horizontal"
    dynamic_title="[email]"
    error_handling="inline"
    include_jquery="no"
    register_member="yes"
    return="/index.php/sign-up/"
    safecracker_head="no"
}

    {if global_errors:count > 0}
    <div class="errors group tencol">
        <h3>General Errors</h3>

        <ul class="bullets">
        {global_errors}
            <li>{error}</li>
        {/global_errors}
        </ul>   
    </div>
    {/if}

    {if field_errors:count > 0}
    <div class="errors group tencol">
        <h3>Form Errors</h3>

        <ul class="bullets">
        {field_errors}
            <li>{error}</li>
        {/field_errors}
        </ul>   
    </div>
    {/if}

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Sign Up</legend>

        <div class="control-group {if error:email != ''}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="email">E-mail<sup class="required">*</sup></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="text" name="email" value="{email}" id="email">
                {if error:email != ''}
                    <span class="help-inline">{error:email}</span>
                {/if}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:password != ''}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="password">Password<sup class="required">*</sup></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                {if error:password != ''}
                    <span class="help-inline">{error:password}</span>
                {/if}               
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group {if error:password_confirm != ''}error{/if}">
            <label class="control-label" for="password_confirm">Password Confirmation<sup class="required">*</sup></label>
            <div class="controls">
                <input type="password" name="password_confirm" id="password_confirm">
                {if error:password_confirm != ''}
                    <span class="help-inline">{error:password_confirm}</span>
                {/if}               
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </fieldset>

{/exp:safecracker}
```

Any idea what is happening?

P.S. I am using ExpressionEngine 2.5.5 and Safecracker Registration 1.2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bug with SafeCracker Registration. EE recently dropped the ip_address field from the security_hashes database and this add-on still acts as if it's there. Try upgrading to the latest version of SafeCracker Registration or contact the developer to make sure they know and can put out a fix.

Comment: Thanks for the report. I will get this fixed. The number schema for EE is a joke. EE 2.5.5 should not break compatibility with EE 2.5.3, alas it does break things.

Comment: I see your point but this change was due to security changes, and the security_hashes table isn't really something we (EllisLab) expect third-party developers to manually use. But we also should have done a developer preview with this release to iron out some kinks, that would have allowed add-on authors to push out fixes sooner.

Comment: The main reason I said it was a joke was because it all started with EE 2.5.3. It introduced bugs that had to be fixed in almost all my add-ons. Then, and once 2.5.4 came out those bugs were fixe and now there is unnecessary bloat in my code to fix what is suppose to a be a maintenance release. It would have been much better to see a version bump to 2.6 and deal with the lineage of code there. Now there are big differences between the API's in 2.5.2, 2.5.3, and now 2.5.5. It's impossible to keep track of for average users. Really appreciate the communication though.

Comment: I'm sure you know any change to software can cause instability. I'm curious to know what your addons are doing that bug fixes seem to have broken them, we can't improve that if you don't communicate these things or choose to complain here or on Twitter instead. Send me an email and we can figure out how to prevent this in the future, kevin.cupp@ellislab.com. It could be that your addons are doing things the API doesn't necessarily support, or there could be a legitimate concern, and I'd like to figure it out.

Comment: I agree with you. I will email you guys directly next time an issues comes up. Appreciate you reaching out here though.

Comment: Ok guys, thanks for the answer. I am aware that this is a bug now.

Answer (score 2):

Per the comments in the other answer, I am working on a fix for this. Email support@objectivehtml.com and I will send you and email with the latest version once it is available.

EDIT:

**I have a fix for these issue now in my latest developer build. Just email me for the latest build.**

Comment: Would it be possible to update the core and make it available for download?

Comment: I can't update the core at this time. This is a major release and has a good deal of documentation to write. I am looking to release in a week or two.